# How to resolve this fatal error: call to undefined function __() in cakephp (version 1.2)

Tags: php, cakephp

How to resolve this `fatal error: call to undefined function __()` in cakephp (version 1.2)

The part of the code that throws the error is:

```
if (isset($myproducts))
            __('Product List for ' . $user_name);
    else
            __('Product List');
```

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: `__()` is available since 2.0

Comment: @Machavity, as i know, it's not belongs to that, It's and version error

Comment: @AbdullaNilam While it could still be a version problem, internationalization support (including the shorthand `__*` functions) is actually available since version 1.2.